# Updates made to application config are only being read correctly in Windows 7 when the application runs as Administrator

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, uac

We have an application that was built for the Windows Mobile and Windows platforms, using Visual Studio 2005. We have both versions of this application developed using a single code base to try and reduce code duplication. One of the issues that we encountered with this was that the ConfigurationManager was not available for the Windows Mobile platform. We worked around this by building our own ConfigurationManager that reads and writes settings to the "Application.exe.config" file in the Program Files folder. So both our Windows version and our Windows Mobile version use this same custom ConfigurationManager.

This worked fine on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, but on Windows 7 we have encountered a problem and I don't know how to work around it. When we make a change to the config file (which we can only do by copying it to another folder, changing it and then copying it back... otherwise we get an "access denied" message when we try to save our changes directly in the Program Files folder), the change that we make is only reflected if we run the application as Administrator. If we run the application as a normal user, the default setting from the install are always shown. We suspect that this is a Windows 7 security-related issue, but can someone explain why this is happening? How can we change the settings so that they are also applied when the application is run as an ordinary user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your app tried to write to the config file at least once running non elevated and without a manifest. This made a "compatibility files" folder for your config file. When you run non elevated it looks there now. (See http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/FindingFilesYoureSureYouWrote.aspx for screenshots of how you can confirm this.)

If all you want is for a human, or some utility program you wrote that can run elevated, to be able to edit the config file, you can leave it where it is and put a manifest on your app to prevent virtualization. See http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/AddingAManifestToAVistaApplication.aspx for a sample manifest. That blog post goes on to tell you how to embed the manifest, but you don't need to, an external manifest will work. If your app is foo.exe, name the manifest foo.exe.manifest and put it in the same folder. This will prevent virtualization and cause the app to read the "real" config file.

If changing the config file will be a normal everyday occurrence, don't write the file under Program Files. AppData is a good choice.

Comment: Perfect, Kate. Thanks. That was the info that I needed. The config that it was reading from was in the "compatibility files". We just deleted that copy and it read the new/correct settings from the config in Program Files. No, changing settings will not be an everyday occurrence, they are set once when the tablet is setup and then are basically never changed again. Anyway, this gave me the info that I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 requires elevated privileges for several folders, including program files. It's not good practice to try to work around this.

Since you are using a custom solution, one option is placing your configuration file under %APPDATA%\yourproduct, which can be reached with

```
var appDataFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, product);
```

A better solution is probably to use different configuration managers for different platforms, though. Couldn't some kind of [abstract factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) be applied?

Comment: Thanks, for this info, havardhu, I will definitely be looking at changing our ConfigurationManager to write to AppData for the windows application.